# Linux Command Not Functioning As Alias

Tags: bash, centos, alias

I've created a command to count the number of sessions each user on our server has. It is:

```
who | awk '{ print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort
```

which works fine, but when I move this into an alias on the server I'm only get the return of `who`,

```
alias who_con="who | awk '{ print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort";
```

I thought it might have been the double quotes so I tried single quotes for the encapsulation but I have the same behavior,

```
alias who_con='who | awk "{ print $1}" | sort | uniq -c | sort';
```

Comment: You should rather state what shell this is, not that it's on Linux. I mean the tags.

Comment: So replace `linux` with `version 4.1.2(1)-release` or what should the tag be?

Comment: It's Bash. `bashrc` is a config file of Bash.

Comment: Aliases have two advantages over shell scripts or shell functions, but if you have neither of those reasons to use them, then you could consider not using them.

Comment: @can-ned_food What are the two advantages you are referring to? Running `who_con` seems like the easiest way to get the result of `who | awk '{ print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort`.

Comment: **(A)** alias expansion is performed repeatedly — though not recursively — and occurs prior to searching $PATH items; **(B)** aliases are expanded in such a way as to not require encapsulating arguments, which they do not support anyway, as you would in shell functions — depending on what you need, this is either an advantage over functions or a disadvantage.  You probably don't want a shell script, but I was merely reminding you that you could consider using shell functions — not that you necessarily should.  Shell functions are overall more versatile, that's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar in `$1`.

```
$ alias wW="who | awk '{ print \$1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort"
$ wW
      1 tomasz
```

`$1` should be expanded by awk, not by the shell. Without the additional escape, it's expanded by the shell. You need one more level of escape. This will also do:

```
$ alias who_con='who | awk "{ print \$1}" | sort | uniq -c | sort';
$ who_con
      1 tomasz
```

Comment: @chris85 I don't see `cat` in your question. I added the other possible quoting to my answer.

Comment: Oh, I meant `awk` not `cat`. I was trying `cat` before. I'll accept this in 3 minutes.

Comment: Ah, that's right! The whole line is expanded twice by the shell, and the single quotes only blocks either the first or the second time from affecting `awk`'s argument, depending on whether they're inner or outer. I suppose `alias what='who | awk '\''{print $1}'\'' | ...'` would also work, but is overkill with only one inner meta-character